# What is the range of a PID on Linux and Solaris?

Tags: linux, solaris, pid

What is the maximum and minimum value for a PID (Process ID) on Linux and Solaris?

Comment: For linux, search " /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max" in https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From http://www.alexxoid.com/blog/linux/getting-the-max-pid-value-for-linux-process.html:

> To get the max PID value that can be assigned to Linux process, run the following command:
>
> ```
> cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
> ```

On most Linux machines, the default value is **32768** (= 2<sup>15</sup>).

However, it can be set to any value **up to 4194304** (= 2<sup>22</sup>) if necessary. Servers might have a larger limit to avoid PID collisions, for example.

Answer (score 16):

You've had, and accepted, a Linux answer.  On Solaris, the maximum value of a process ID is a kernel tunable parameter — [`pidmax`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-4015/chapter2-107/index.html) in `/etc/system` — that defaults to 30,000 and that can be set anywhere between 266 and 999,999.  Note that this is not `max_nprocs`, which is a kernel tunable parameter with a subtly different function.

Comment: You mentioned that `max_nprocs` is different, what's the difference?

Comment: @ffledgling `max_nprocs` limits the number of concurrent processes, regardless of whether unused pids are available or not.

Answer (score 2):

The minimum is 1 and usually the maximum is 2^15

Comment: ... except on Solaris, as in the question, where it isn't.

Comment: The minimum PID is actually 0, i.e. the kernel which isn't a process really ...

Comment: do the kernel get a PID?

Comment: It doesn't need one but is given pid 0. Under Linux, I guess it is only shown as a PPID but under Solaris, there is definitely a /proc/0 entry and ps reports process 0 as "sched".

Comment: @jlliagre ubuntu has no `/proc/0` neither `ps -p 0` works :), anyway, as a variable pid initializer, the best seems to be `-1`

Comment: @AquariusPower but Linux does report anyway PID 0 as the parent process for at least `init` or `systemd`, plus `kthreadd`. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13290/init-process-ancestor-of-all-processes

Comment: @jlliagre interesting, the answer there also says that pid 0 means a process without parent, like a process running directly in the kernel; well, processes have to run in some environment that manages them, that is the kernel, therefore the self kernel cannot be a process inside of it-self. If a system gives access to pid 0 in some way, probably is to allow the user to query the kernel it-self, like a marker/indicator/reference, but not a process; that is what I think :)

Comment: @AquariusPower The kernel is indeed not a process or at least an extremely special one, but it is nevertheless given a process ID which is what the question is about.

Comment: @AquariusPower From `man kill`: "A PID of -1 is special; it indicates all processes except the kill process itself and init."